# Scala protected object

Tags: scala, protected

In Scala, if I create an object and companion class, identifiers declared with the `protected` modifier can be accessed from the class if the object is imported:

```
object Foo {
  protected val X = 42
}
class Foo {
  import Foo._
  def getX(): Int = X
}
```

However, the `protected` identifier cannot be accessed from a subclass of the class Foo:

```
class Bar extends Foo {
  import Foo._
  def getX(): Int = X * 2
}
```

I get a compile-time error in `Bar`.

Other then (implied) `public`, is there any access modifier I can place on `X` so that it can be accessed from subclasses of its companion, but not from other classes, including other classes in the same package?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because only the class `Foo` is companion to the object `Foo`.

Here, the difference between `private` and `protected` meaningless, since the object `Foo` is a *singleton*, which means there isn't any other object that has the same class as object `Foo` (`Foo.type`).

Access restriction in Scala is package-based, so the short answer is no. You could make a forwarder on the base class, though, unless you need it to be available without an instance.

In your place, however, I'd go back to the design board.

Answer (score 3):

In such cases, I would suggest using a package private modifier, like below:

```
object Foo {
  private[your_package] val X = 42
}
```

The value will still be visible to everybody else in the package.

Comment: Just a small issue: your subclass is not always in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the same thing, One solution to this problem can be:

```
class Bar extends Foo {
  import Foo._
  override def getX(): Int = super.getX * 2
}
```